# No labels on my map using MapLibre GL JS (serving tiles locally)

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I'm serving my own tiles using protomaps/go-pmtiles , and the tiles are getting displayed.

But I'm getting no labels on the map. What I'm I doing wrong?

##### UPDATE:

I got my data from **geofabrik.de**, rendered them using **tilemaker** to **.mbtiles**, served them using **tileserver-gl** and had **maplibre** as my client.

I'm using the default fonts and styles provided by the test data of tileserver-gl, which is **osm-bright** and **Open Sans**, located [here](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl/releases/download/v1.3.0/test_data.zip).

I'm doing these steps for data of Iran, which has non-latin and Persian labels. The problem is, while it perfectly serves the maps, it shows no labels.

To make sure, I did all of these steps with an state of the united states, and everything worked perfectly, including the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is very little information here.

But in my experience, when everything works except labels, the usual cause is not providing a source of text glyphs. The style file contains a `glyphs` element ([docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/glyphs/)) which needs to point somewhere usable. If you're not using the Mapbox servers, you'll need to find another source.

Comment: I tried again with tileserver-gl, maplibre and mbtiles and had the same result. Full map, no labels. I'm doing this with map of Iran which has Persian names. I tried the map of a United States city (english names) and everything worked perfectly, including the labels. So maybe the labels not being in Latin is the problem?

Comment: If you provide a lot more information about your setup, perhaps people can help you.

Comment: check out the update of the og post

Answer (score 0):

check the "text-font" of your style file. If the label's 'text-font' not configured maplibre will use the default. If the default is not in the style file the label will not showing.